# How to name unused parameters?

Tags: parameters, coding-style

I have defined an interface (via duck typing in this case) which requires to implement a method with the following signature:

```
def check(self, field_value, domain_object)
```

In some cases it is not necessary to use the last parameter. But what is a good style to name unused parameters?

Maybe `def check(self, field_value, unused)`?

Comment: I would continue using a meaningful name. If the parameter is never used, just get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call it `unused_parameter` just to make even clearer that it isn't a required boolean parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Because this looks like Ruby, you could just write:

```
def check(self, field_value, domain_object = nil)  // dont know the exact syntax!
```

But never get rid of a meaningfull name!!

Or you could declare a second method that does the same thing, but without the third parameter.
E.g.:

```
def check(self, field_value)  
def checkAgainstDomainObject(self, field_value, domain_object)
```